# Is the Gibbs-Duhem equation always valid?

Tags: thermodynamics, potential

The derivation of the Gibbs-Duhem equation from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs%E2%80%93Duhem_equation#Derivation) uses:

> As shown in the [Gibbs free energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_free_energy) article, the chemical potential is just another name for the partial molar (or just partial, depending on the units of $N$) Gibbs free energy, thus
> $$G = \sum_{i=1}^I \mu_i N_i \,. $$

On the other hand, that article [states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_free_energy#Homogeneous_systems):

> Because some of the natural variables are intensive, $dG$ may not be
> integrated using Euler integrals as is the case with internal energy.
> However, simply substituting the Gibbs-Duhem relation result for $U$
> into the definition of $G$ gives a standard expression for $G$:[<sup>[12]</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_free_energy#cite_note-Salzman2001-12)
>
> $$\begin{align} G &= T S - p V + \sum_i \mu_i N_i + p V - T S\\ &= \sum_i \mu_i N_i \end{align}$$
>
> **This result applies to homogeneous, macroscopic systems, but not to
> all thermodynamic systems.[<sup>[13]</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_free_energy#cite_note-13)**
>
> ---
>
> [12] Salzman, William R. (2001-08-21). ["Open Systems"](http://web.archive.org/web/20070707224025/http://www.chem.arizona.edu/%7Esalzmanr/480a/480ants/opensys/opensys.html). Chemical Thermodynamics. University of Arizona. Archived from [the original](http://www.chem.arizona.edu/%7Esalzmanr/480a/480ants/opensys/opensys.html) on 2007-07-07. Retrieved 2007-10-11.
> [13] Brachman, M. K. (1954). "Fermi Level, Chemical Potential, and Gibbs Free Energy". The Journal of Chemical Physics 22 (6): 1152–1151. doi:[10.1063/1.1740312](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1740312).

This sounds like circular reasoning to me, or did I miss something? Anyway, my question is about the emphasized last sentence, in short:

> *When* is the Gibbs-Duhem equation *not* valid? Is there a well-known example?

Comment: (or, apparently equivalent, when is $G\neq\sum_i\mu_i N_i$?)

Answer (score 2):

I think your question is really: Why is Gibbs-Duhem equation not valid for inhomogeneous and/or small systems? This is related to why Thermodynamics does not apply to these systems. Examples, discussion and a Thermodynamical theory for these systems can be found in Terrell Hill's works [link](https://doi.org/10.1021/nl010010d).

But in short: both inhomogeneous and few-body systems have more degrees of freedom than their macroscopic homogeneous counterparts. So in the former ones, the Gibbs-Duhem relation is different and no longer restricts the changes in the intensive variables by allowing only 2 of them to be independent. Also Gibbs potential will need the addition of a term related to the new ways in which energy can be transformed.